# I want to stop a thread of squaring function in python but it is not working?

Tags: python, multithreading, multitasking

I have created a function of squares which will start squaring from 1,2... when i will type "start" and  end up squaring when i will type "stop".
When i typed "start",i started getting squares of numbers after every 2 sec but when i typed "stop",the thread didnt stop.I used the variable 'flag' to stop the function.
Here is the code.

```
import threading
import time
flag=False
def square():
    i=1;
    global flag
    while(True):
        print(i*i,"\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        i=i+1
        if(flag):
            break

def main():
    while(True):
        x=input("Enter start/stop")
        if(x=="start"):
            flag=False
            p = threading.Thread(target=square)
            p.start()
        if(x=="stop"):
            flag=True
            p.join()

main()
```

Comment: Add a `global flag` in *main*.

Comment: Thank you @CristiFati Now,its working

Comment: Change `while(True):` to `while(flag==False):` and then you can remove the `if(flag): break`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the *flag* variable defined and used in *main* was local, and had nothing to do with the one used by the thread, so the thread was never notified by its change (and therefore newer knew when it was time to stop). 
The fix is simple, make the variable global in *main* (same way as already done in *square*):

```py
global flag
```

*square* function could be also simplified, instead of:

```
while True:
# The other instructions
if(flag):
    break
```

you could do:

```
while not flag:
    # The other instructions
```

As a note, there are other ways of synchronizing between threads, *e.g.*:

- `threading.Event`
- make your thread a ***daemon*** (`p = threading.Thread(target=square, daemon=True)`, even if generally not recommended), meaning that it will abruptly stop when *main* will reach its end

For more info, check [[Python 3.docs]: threading - Thread-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).